# Lumia phone Licence not recognised + no emails

Tags: email

[image]Lumia 635, I have used this phone for more than 12 months with few problems. Over the last few months I get a message saying Licence not recognised, when I tap on Explorer logo it takes me to BT Fon, not explorer..... Then yesterday my emails [Outlook] stopped appearing on the phone [Still appearing on PC] 
One thing that really annoys me, this is a Microsoft, Windows 10 phone, so how can a licence be 'issued' by Microsoft that is incorrect?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error message you're getting? That does not sound like something Windows 10 Mobile would display. Maybe it's from a carrier-installed app?

Comment: I have scanned the screen message - but I do not know how to attach it & send to you?  Emails seem to be coming to the phone after a day without them? no idea what happened there?

Comment: To add an image to your post, simply click the "edit" link under it, then click the image icon in the toolbar (or press Ctrl+G) and upload your screenshot. If the screenshot is on your phone, use OneDrive, a USB cable, Bluetooth or some other method to get it to your PC. You can also just upload it to any image host (like imgur.com) and post the link here, and someone will edit it into your post.

Comment: Is that the error message you're getting? That's a certificate error in Internet Explorer. Can you clarify how exactly you're getting that error, and how it's affecting your using the phone?